# Select a part in a string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have string

```
string AccountName= "123456789 - Savings - 20$"
```

Now I want to select the Accountname Savings only. That means the part between -s.

That data is dynamic data. So, Could you please give me an idea to get **the part of string between two -s.** i.e AccountName= "Savings".

Thank you in advance..!!

Comment: Please be more clear. What is the expected output?

Comment: I updated it.. Please look at my query again. thanks

Comment: you could use regex. `"[Ss]\S+[Ss]"`

Comment: do a simple google search on `C# string.Split()` function. this is not that difficult

Comment: If you want to be a programmer then you should learn how to read the documentation. The [string class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) has many methods that you can use to reach your goal. Try something then ask if you have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your string will always have only two -s, you could using the following to get the substring between them. If this is not the case please modify the question to better describe the issue.

```
string myString = AccountName.Split('-')[1];
```

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx for more information on the Split method in the string class.

Comment: Thank you. It worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can to that:

- Split string by '-'
- Get the position 1 of array
- Trim value to remove spaces

  var AccountNameSplited= AccountName.split('-')[1].Trim();

You should be defensive in this cases:

```
var AccountNameBt = AccountName.Split('-');
var AccountNameBtPos1 = string.Empty;
if (AccountNameBt != null && AccountNameBt.Count() > 0)
AccountNameBtPos1 =AccountNameBt[1].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
string AccountName = "123456789 - Savings - 20$";

String[] tokens = AccountName.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
AccountName = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(1);  // Savings
```

If it's possible that there are no spaces:

```
String[] tokens = AccountName.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
AccountName = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(1)?.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
AccountName = Regex.Match(AccountName, @"-\s*(.*?)\s*-").Groups[1].Value;
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Xr24T